# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 2 Foreign Keys from the same table exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables and models corresponding to each table: Employee and EmployeeEducation 
In EmployeeEducation I have 2 foreign keys from the table Employee: Id for consultant and id for actual employee who owns the educations. Each education can have different consultant.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact Admin")]
[Display(Name = "Consultant")]
public int? ConsultantId { get; set; }
*emphasized text*
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact Admin")]
public int? EmployeeId { get; set; }
```

For each id ı have these objects to reach the objects

```
[ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ConsultantId")]
public virtual Employee Consultant { get; set; }
```

When I run the code and try to enter an education to the employee with the consultant it gives me following exception with an inner exception.

```
EntityCommandExecutionException 
{"An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."}

Inner exception: SqlCeException
{"The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = Extent1,Column name = Employee_Id ]"}
```

But when I remove Consultant object it does not give an exception.
How can I solve this problem so that i have access to both Consultant and Employee itself?

The exception happens in DetailsEducation.cshtml:

```
@{ if (Model.EducationList == null || !Model.EducationList.Any())
    {
```

Here is how EducationList is populated:

```
public ActionResult DetailsEducation(int id) 
{ 
  Employee employee = _work.EmployeeRepository.GetSet()
    .Include(a => a.EducationList)
    .Include(a => a.EducationList.Select(c => c.University))
    .Include(a => a.EducationList.Select(c => c.Department))
    .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id); 
  return PartialView("_DetailsEducation", employee);
}
```

Comment: 1) Can you show us the code that gives the exception? 2) Note that Employee_Id from the error message differs from EmployeeId from the attribute. This may or may not matter.

Comment: it gives the exception at DetailsEducation.cshtml at:
@{if (Model.EducationList == null || !Model.EducationList.Any())
  {
Model is an Employee object that holds 
public virtual ICollection<EmployeeEducation> EducationList { get; set; }

Comment: What is the code that sets `Model.EducationList` ?

Comment: It is in the controller the following code piece where id is the employeeid of the viewed person  public ActionResult DetailsEducation(int id)
        {
  Employee employee = _work.EmployeeRepository.GetSet().
                Include(a => a.EducationList).
                Include(a => a.EducationList.Select(c => c.University)).Include(a => a.EducationList.Select(c => c.Department)).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
            return PartialView("_DetailsEducation", employee);}

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with you Entity Framework model. It does not seem to match to your database schema. Was the DB changed recently without EF model being updated to accommodate it? You can fire up the SQL Profiler and see how the request is coming through. I bet that the SQL will include Employee_Id that is absent in the DB. You will have to update your EF model so that this mismatch is corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Column name = Employee_Id**

When Entity Framework creates a SQL query with a foreign key that has an (unexpected) underscore in its column name it is almost always an indicator that EF infers a relationship by convention and that is another one than the relationship you have defined with annotations or Fluent API.

This foreign key cannot origin from the `EmployeeEducation.Employee` and `EmployeeEducation.Consultant` navigation properties because for those you have defined the foreign key name with data annotations `[ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]` and `[ForeignKey("ConsultantId")]`.

Now, how does EF detect relationships? It inspects the navigation properties in your model classes. We already know that `EmployeeEducation.Employee` and `EmployeeEducation.Consultant` cannot be the problem, so there must be a third navigation property somewhere. The relationship that belongs to this navigation property must have an association end in `EmployeeEducation` because EF apparently infers the need of an additional foreign key `Employee_Id` in the `EmployeeEducation` table.

Because of the name - **Employee** _Id - this navigation property will be in your class `Employee`. Looking at your `Include(a => a.EducationList)` you seem to have a collection property in `Employee`:

```
public SomeCollectionType<EmployeeEducation> EducationList { get; set; }
```

This collection is most likely causing the third foreign key. If you had only one navigation property in `EmployeeEducation`, for example only `EmployeeEducation.Employee`, the problem would not occur because EF would infer in this case that `Employee.EducationList` and `EmployeeEducation.Employee` are a pair of navigation properties of a single relationship.

If you have *two* navigation properties both refering to `Employee` EF cannot decide which of the two the collection in `Employee` belongs to. Instead of choosing one by whatever rule it chooses none of them and assumes that the collection belongs to a third relationship.

To solve the problem you must EF give a hint which of the two references in `EmployeeEducation` you want to relate the collection to, for example by using the `[InverseProperty]` attribute on one of the properties (but not both):

```
[ForeignKey("EmployeeId"), InverseProperty("EducationList")]
public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ConsultantId")]
public virtual Employee Consultant { get; set; }
```

Attention: The `EducationList` will only contain `EmployeeEducation`s the given employee is `Employee` for, but not `Consultant`. For that you would need a second collection property in `Employee` with an `[InverseProperty]` annotation on `Consultant` this time. Generally you cannot associate *one* navigation collection in one entity to *two* navigation references in the other entity. Your only choice are either two collections or no collection at all. (In the latter case your problem would disappear as well by the way, but you wouldn't have a navigation property anymore you could "include".)