# EF 4.1 code first with one-to-many relationship creates duplicate foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I am using entity framework code first. I have 2 entities (Users and Profile) and the relationship between them is one-to-many, that is, one user can only have one profile, but one profile can be assigned to many users. Below the entities:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key(), Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Profile")]
    public virtual int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AnotherEntityB> anotherEntityB { get; set; } 
}

[Table("Profiles")]
public class Profile
{
    [Key(), Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    // Below the user that performs the discharge of the profile. Only 1 user can do it.
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public virtual int? UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? dischargeDate { get; set; } <-- this is the date that user performs the discharge of the profile

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<AnotherEntityC> anotherEntityC { get; set; }
}
```

also I have removed some conventions in the OnModelCreating method:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

The problem is that EF is creating two foreign keys in user entity:

```
ProfileId (FK, int, No NULL)
Profile_Id (FK, int, NULL)
```

and only one foreign key should be in Users entity:
    ProfileId (FK, int, No NULL)

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there are *two* navigation properties `User` and `Users` in `Profile` that refer to the `User` entity EF cannot decide by a convention which of the two belongs to the inverse property `Profile` in entity `User`. You must EF give a hint using the `[InverseProperty]` attribute:

```
[InverseProperty("Users")]
public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
```

Now, it defines that `User.Profile` is the inverse navigation property of `Profile.Users` and that both are ends of the same relationship. Without the attribute EF assumes that the two navigation properties are ends of two different relationships and one of them is responsible for the additional foreign key `Profile_Id`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16532134/270591) is a bit more background.

Comment: It works like a charm! many thanks! Another approach that works is by overriding OnModelCreating and putting this:            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasRequired(r => r.Profile)
                .WithMany(s => s.Users)
                .HasForeignKey(f => f.ProfileId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

Comment: @user1624552: Yes, that's the Fluent version. I thought you are working with annotations because you already had some attributes in your model. But if you want to disable cascading delete you even **must** use the Fluent version. The attribute configuration in my answer would correspond to the default for required relationships which is `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)`.